# Store value to NSObject from Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

it is my first time to use json result and save it to an object as my goal.

i have this as my sample json.

```
{"corpUserWs":{"loginMsg":"User is locked out. Please request for your account to be unlocked.","requestStatus":0,"sessionId":"16gxtse746yqj"}}
```

and i have a code here

```
NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"corpUserWs"]);
```

that return this result

```
{
loginMsg = "User is locked out. Please request for your account to be unlocked.";
requestStatus = 0;
sessionId = 16gxtse746yqj;
}
```

but what i want is to store the result in a object which i declared. LogIn object with 3 properties - loginMsg, requestStatus, sessionId.

I've tried to research on how to get the value "loginMsg" or any data inside the corpUserWs. Please help me into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary*)[json objectForKey:@"corpUserWs"];

LogIn *login = [[LogIn alloc] init];
login.loginMsg = data[@"loginMsg"];
login.requestStatus = data[@"requestStatus"];
login.sessionId = data[@"loginMsg"];
```

But you probably will have to cast values to proper data types

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an entity named "LoginResult" with the following properties:

```
@interface LoginResult : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* loginMsg
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* requestStatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* sessionId;

@end
```

One could populate a new entity with the following code:

```
-(LoginResult*)populateFromJson:(NSString*)responseString {

    NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; 
    json = [json objectForKey:@"corpUserWs"];

    LoginResult* result = [LoginResult new];
    result.loginMsg = json[@"loginMsg"];
    result.requestStatus = json[@"requestStatus"];
    result.sessionId = json[@"sessionId"];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the keys in the json dictionary and the properties of your model object are names the same, you kan unse Key-Value-Coding to set all properties:

```
NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
LoginResult* result = [LoginResult new];
for (NSString *key in jsonDict){
    [result setValue:jsondict[key] forKey:key]; 
}
```